# Is there any constrain for using STL containers (vector, etc) in boost::thread_specific_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, stl

I'm currently working on a project requiring per thread storage for caching fetched data. I'm looking into boost::thread_specific_ptr for solution, but I'm still not very clear on the following aspects:

Where is that object thread_specific_ptr pointed to actually allocated in process address space? Are those in special segments like bss, data or others? Will that be protected so that any other threads in the same process could not examine the address where the object is located? If it is a special memory section, will it be dangerous to use STL containers in boost::thread_specific_ptr since it could auto resize itself when more data is added till crossing the section boundary?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread-local pointers are platform dependent, but the object you store *via* it is just on the heap.

The only thing really thread local is a pointer to it, and the operating system/runtime library will have some thread-associated storage to keep them in. That's an implementation detail, and you don't have to worry about it.

If you plan on storing a lot of containers, consider storing one structure that contains (pointers to) them all.

Also, use thread-local storage sparingly. Depending on them is a design smell in my book. You might simply require process isolation, instead of threads.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So by saying "object you store via it is just on the heap", you mean that if I use boost::thread_specific_ptr(std::vector) like stuff, both the vector itself and its contents will be in the heap, right?

Comment: Yes. (What else). It's called `thread_specific_ptr` for that reason, actually.